# Can I shoot an eagle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can an eagle take an arrow in the knee?

Just kidding. But seriously, is it possible to actually land an arrow in a flying eagle?
I´ve tried with about 200 arrows without any success.

Comment: I wouldn't want your character to shoot an apple in my head.

Comment: Spells also work.

Comment: Spells are far more easy in that case. I'm puting birds on fire every time I visit Solitude.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you mean hawk, yes you can.  You have to be within range, but if you do shoot one, you'll be able to collect the hawk feathers and hawk beak for alchemy as they're fairly hard to obtain.

Comment: 24 seconds. This is the price of 2 asterisks and a pound.

Comment: Sorry about my lack of biology knowledge. I meant hawk.

Comment: @LessPop you got more rep out of your answer than me since I was almost capped out anyway ;)

Comment: Easy if you use lightning spells, those are basically hitscan. Hawks give some good potion ingredients, so shooting a few of them down is nice.

Comment: The Skyrim wikia also lists that the Kyne's Peace shout is an easy way to insta-kill hawks. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Also, Elder Scrolls realism is in effect here: eating hawk feathers will cure everything from Rockjoint to cancer.

Answer (score 41):

Is it possible to hit a bird? Yes.

Is it *incredibly difficult*?

## **YES.**

The best place to try is Solitude - you can use the bridges between the towers to get to a decent altitude, the birds fly relatively low, and you're in a separate zone from the main game world, so range is less likely to be an issue.

Having a full complement of Archery perks makes an enormous difference as well, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 4):

With a full compliment of archery, you can use the right click of the mouse to zoom. Your sightvisor doesn't move everywhere. It's really easy to kill an eagle in Solitude, Eagles which are flying over the port.

Answer (score 4):

go to the archery menu and get the zoom with the bow ability and the extra damage and range. As well as get the one where when you hold your breath you can slow down time to get a better aim, if your stamina is high. You can hold down your breath for a solid 30+ seconds. also you can earn a shout which nearly freezes time. The 2 together can make them really slow. Solitude is a good place. But you can *also* use lightning.

Answer (score 4):

You can kill them, by they're not actually entities as far as the game engine is concerned. They're just static models that are animated to fly around and occasionally nest, but if it detects an arrow or projectile near enough (it doesn't have to be a perfect hit), the game despawns the static model and replaces it with a havoked lootable corpse, which then falls to the ground. The more you know.

And as far as I can tell, they drop 1 hawk beak and 3 hawk feathers 100% of the time. They also respawn after a few days. Good source of ingredients.

Also, I find it pretty easy to free-aim them in Solitude, down the main street. (By free-aim I mean with the crosshair turned off in the settings.) Just remember to shoot slightly ahead of them, and it helps if you also wait till they're above the main street so the body lands in an accessible place.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but extremely difficult, as stated above, archery perks help, if you have dawnguard, I recommend using a crossbow. Or even magic. Ice spear is very useful.