# What do I need to make the Potion of Strength?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anyone know what (if any) ingredients I can use to make the potion of strength in Skyrim?

Comment: What do you mean by Strength Potion, weapon damage or carry weight?

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ingredients that have the "[Fortify Carry Weight](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Carry_Weight)" attribute:

- Creep Cluster
- Giant's Toe
- Hawk Beak
- River Betty
- Scaly Pholiota
- Wisp Wrappings

Bryan points out that the following combos have additional effects:

- Creep Cluster + Giant's Toe = Damage Stamina Regen
- Creep Cluster + Scaly Pholiota = Weakness to Magic
- Hawk Beak + Wisp Wrappings = **Restore Stamina**

I'd avoid the two combinations which yield poison effects, unless you have the relevant alchemy skills to negate them.

Creep Clusters are pretty easy to find, and Giant's Toes are easy to *find* but not so easy to separate from the rest of the giant.  Scaly Pholiota are found growing on trees and stumps and the like.  Those are probably the easiest to find in normal situations.

Hawk Beaks generally require that you kill hawks, which is not that easy to do.  We covered killing them [in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46634/can-i-shoot-an-eagle) although Bryan also points out that lightning spells work well as well.  Wisp Wrappings are relatively rare in shops (killing Wisps yields them the most often), and River Betties are a type of fish in streams and lakes, which may be a bit tricky to find in large quantities.

Comment: +1, but in addendum: Hawks = kill with lightning in Solitude. Orders of magnitude easier than using fireballs or arrows. Creep Cluster + Giant's Toe = Damage Stamina Regen. Creep Cluster + Scaly Pholiota = Weakness to Magic. Hawk Beak + Wisp Wrappings = Restore Stamina. Giant's Toes are also great, of course, for their super-long, super-expensive Fortify Health effect.

Comment: @desaivv Just checked [an online tool](http://sinderion.herokuapp.com/). If you click Fortify Carry Weight you can hover over the other effects and see if there are matches.